# How to compare two arrays using tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, compare, tensor

I need to compare two arrays and get either true or false,not elementwise result. My code is

```
X = tf.constant([0.05, 0.10], dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 2])
y = tf.constant([0.01, 0.99], dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 2])

equality = tf.equal(X, y)
```

prints [False, False]

my requirement is to get true or false, not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to return `False` if **any** of your values are not equal then you can use the [reduce_all](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_all) operation:

```py
equality = tf.math.reduce_all(tf.equal(X, y))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.At the same time i got the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I got solution.

```
equality = tf.equal(X, y)   
reduce_t = tf.reduce_all(equality)
print(sess.run(reduce_t))
```