# Compare two tensors of numpy arrays by each array - tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow

I have a multilabel classification problem and my `y_true` and `y_pred` during training looks like this:

```py
y_true = tf.constant([[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]])
y_pred = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

I want to compare those two based on each pair of lists.
To do so, I wrote something like

```py
values = tf.cast(x, "float32") == tf.cast(y, "float32")
bool_to_number_values = tf.cast(tranformed_values, "float32")
print(bool_to_number_values)
tranformed_values_summed = x.numpy().shape[0] - tf.reduce_sum(bool_to_number_values)
tranformed_values_summed.numpy()
```

This returns

```py
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32)
```

and `-4.0` because `2.0 - 6.0 == -4.0`

But I don't want this. I want to compare the first array of `y_true` to the first array of `y_pred` and if they are identical return `True` else `False`. The same logic applies for the second array of `y_true` and `y_pred`.

So the correct result should be

```
tf.Tensor(
[0,
 1], , shape=(2,), dtype=float32)

#0: because the arrays on index 0 are not equal y_true[0] <> y_pred[0]
#1: because the arrays on index 1 are equal y_true[1] == y_pred[1]
```

and the `tranformed_values_summed.numpy() = 2.0 - 1.0 = 1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [`tf.reduce_all`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_all):

```
tf.cast(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1), tf.int32)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1])>
```

Copy/pastable:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.constant([[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]])
y_pred = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]])

tf.cast(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1), tf.int32)
```

Comment: Nicolas thanks a lot for your answer. Imagine that I have used ```reduce_all``` after checking this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394240/how-to-compare-two-arrays-using-tensorflow...Although, I missed ```axis=-1``` which made the trick.

Comment: It happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: Nicolas could please check (on your spare time) this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65381855/custom-zero-one-loss-metric-function-is-not-correctly-calculated-during-keras-ne Glad to receive your thoughts about it.